# How can get total amount users without duplicate?

Tags: mysql

I have the table payments, I need get total amount users with a limit 3

```
SELECT SUM(money),username FROM `payments` ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 3
```

Table:

```
+----------+--------+
| username | money  |
+----------+--------+
| Alex     | 200    |
+----------+--------+
| Alex     | 100    |
+----------+--------+
| John     | 50     |
+----------+--------+
| Emily    | 400    |
+----------+--------+
| etc ...
```

How i can get this result? :

```
+----------+--------+
| username | amount |
+----------+--------+
| Emily    | 400    |
+----------+--------+
| Alex     | 300    |
+----------+--------+
| John     | 50     |
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: amount OF users? Or amount owed BY users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you need user wise total so, you've to add group by clause

You can try below - you need to add `group by clause`

```
SELECT username, SUM(money) AS amount
FROM payments
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: why does this work? What did you do? Explain your answer

Comment: A few rough spots, but you basically had the answer quickly +1.

Comment: Thank you ! i forgot about group by )